# Using dictionaries for conditional execution instead of if..elif

Tags: python, if-statement, data-structures, dictionary

Say you have something like below:

```
def case_A():
   print 'A'

def case_B():
   print 'B'

def case_generic():
   print 'some generic case'
```

And `value` is defined and has some value in it

Do you see any scenario(s) where you wouldn't want to apply the pattern below:

```
v = {"A":case_A, "B":case_B}
try:
   v[value]()
except:
   case_generic()
```

instead of the standard:

```
if value == "A":
   case_A()

elif value == "B":
   case_B()

...place n more if cases here...

else:
   case_generic()
```

To me the first case looks way more compact and easy to manage, albeit with a slight increase in memory. Alternatively, do you see any ways of improving the above or using a better way alltogether?

Comment: Basically codereview, right?

Comment: Sort of, I've been thinking about how to achieve branching without using conditionals and been playing with the above wondering under which scenarios it will be inneficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do :

```
v.get(value, case_generic)()
```

Comment: All 3 answers are good but this one wins over with its simplicity and avoiding using exceptions or lamda

Answer (score 3):

[EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) is a common coding style in Python due to its emphasis on conciseness and readability and can result in fast, efficient, and readable code.
In other languages, using exceptions as control flow as opposed to truly exceptional reasons is frowned upon (see [Joshua Bloch, Effective Java, Item 57](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-57-use-exceptions-only-for.html)).

But you don't want to have a generic `except` clause, because this swallows any type of possible exception that could occur in the execution of the code. Rather, you want to be very explicit in the exception you're catching which makes it very clear to any reader that you're checking for keys:

```
try:
    v[value]()
except KeyError: # Key doesn't exist in dictionary
    case_generic()
```

Comment: good background points

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems by using this method, but it can be improved by using a `defaultdict`:

```
v = defaultdict(lambda: case_generic)
v.update({"A": case_A, "B": case_B})

v['A']() # 'A'
v['B']() # 'B'
v['K']() # 'some generic case'
```